# 80s-90s novel about reptilian overlords, with "east" or "west" in the title

Tags: story-identification, novel, parallel-universe

Novel about a parallel world where the dominant species is reptilian. Some humans (or a human?) are captured and their way of life is threatened. Very severe race with different clans at war with each other.

Read this 25-30 years ago. I think the word "east" or "west" is in the title.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in any more details you may remember.

Comment: I would have ironically suggested David Icke's "The Biggest Secret", but he intended it as non-fiction, thinks the situation is in our world (not a parallel world), and "west" isn't in the title.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q="West+of+Eden" . Rly?

Comment: @labyrinth - This is the correct answer. There are seven clans of reptilians (from Annunaki to Grays), and they are in competition. They dominant humanity, and capture them for their experiments. Wake up America!

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Yep, but can't mark any of them as dupe until they have accepted answers.

Comment: It may well be that the source of your confusion about it being East or West in the title stems from the fact that there was a popular film (non SF) called "East of Eden".

Answer (score 21):

Not much to go on here, but this might be *West of Eden* (1984) by Harry Harrison.  The protagonist is a human(ish) who was raised by the dinosaurs who had recently discovered and begun to colonize what we'd think of as the new world.  As a young adult, he is "rescued" by another group of humans, and has to adjust to living among his own kind, then to act as an intermediary between the humans and the dinosaur folk.

There was also a sequel that retconned around the fact that humans (in our world) descended from African apes, so shouldn't have occurred in a world where the dinosaurs never relinquished the Old World.

Answer (score 16):

That will be [*West of Eden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_of_Eden) by Harry Harrison, first published in 1984. It's an alternate history in which the dominant species on Earth is indeed reptilian.

[image: book cover: man and kneeling woman looking at a distant city from a cliff]

> The intelligent reptiloid species is called the Yilanè, and represents the dominant life form on most of the planet. However, during the evolutionary process, the species became non-viable on the North American continent and Caribbean area, leaving them free of Yilanè for millions of years and opening an ecological niche for a top predator. A human-like species, the Tanu, evolved to fill the niche in North America, but are only found on that continent. Unlike humans, which evolved from African primates, the Tanu have evolved from a lineage of New World monkey. By the time the novel begins, the humanoids have reached a late stone age level of technology and culture, with a number of societies having developed farming skills.